# Purescript: convert Char to Lowercase version

Tags: purescript

What is the better way to convert a given `Char` to lowercase version?

One method could be with converting to `String`:

```
charToLower :: Char -> Char
charToLower char =
   Maybe.fromMaybe char 
     $ CodeUnits.charAt 0 
     $ String.toLower 
     $ CodeUnits.singleton char
```

Is there a more appropriate way in terms of performance/simplicity?

There is also a [toLower` from CodePoint.Unicode](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-unicode/5.0.0/docs/Data.CodePoint.Unicode#v:toLower) package but I wonder if it is a preferred way.

Comment: https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-strings/3.0.0/docs/Data.Char#v:toLower

Comment: It is an old version of the package.

Comment: apologies - you're quite correct. That will teach me for just googling and going with the first thing I found! I'd be very surprised if a basic and fundamental function like `toLower` has been completely removed in a later version but you may be right, I haven't found it so far.

Comment: There is one https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-unicode/5.0.0/docs/Data.CodePoint.Unicode#v:toLower but I wonder if it is a preferred way.

Comment: I'd say yes go with the one from `unicode`

Comment: Well i'm not sure how it can make things better though, it is really not clear how to go from CodePoints -> Char without converting to Stirng.

Comment: Here the thing: lower/uppercase conversion of a char sometimes results in more than one char. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62769106/unable-to-get-uppercase-to-%C3%9F-german-character-called-eszett That's why the type signatures in purescript-unicode are what they are.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the fastest way is just to use FFI. One can easily write `toLower` this way:

```js
// Foreign/Char.js

module.exports.toLower = function charToLower(c) {
  return c.toLower();
}
```

```hs
-- Foreign/Char.purs
module Foreign.Char where

foreign import toLower :: Char -> Char
```

Or if you want to express it in purescript only:

```hs
import Unsafe.Coerce (unsafeCoerce)
import Data.String as S

toLower :: Char -> Char
toLower = unsafeCoerce >>> S.toLower >>> unsafeCoerce
```

That eventually boils down to the same js code. You cannot break `Char`'s invariants as it's initially just a subset of `String` and has the same runtime representation.

Comment: This is a valid method, but only if you need performance badly.

Comment: Given:
1. an input `Char` value is just a single character `String` limited to unicode's Plane 0 space (justifies first unsafeCoerce)
2. any lowercased character from unicode's Plane 0 lies within the same plane (justifies second unsafeCoerce)

The output of this function pretty much fullfills the `Char` requirements and the function itself must be type safe.