# Convert lower case letter 'ß' to upper case letter 'ẞ' in PHP

Tags: php, string, utf-8, linguistics

I'm trying to convert the lower case letter 'ß' to the upper case pendant. I already tried using the built-in functions `strtoupper` and `mb_strtoupper`.

The following happened when I use `strtoupper`:

```
echo strtoupper('ß'); // leads to 'ß'
```

The following happened when I use `mb_strtoupper`:

```
echo mb_strtoupper('ß', 'UTF-8'); // leads to 'SS'
```

Comment: could you not use str_replace ?

Comment: I probably could, but I'm actually interested, why the 'ß' is getting converted to 'SS'.

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76696 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/29846109/2943403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this answer for why Python has a similar behaviour https://stackoverflow.com/a/62769447/11924322

This explains why PHP also has this behaviour.

Comment: When you can resolve a new question with a pre-existing page/answer on Stack Overflow, then please do not post an answer.  The appropriate resolution would be to flag/vote to close the page as a duplicate.

Comment: @mickmackusa actually it was a PHP specific question, but the answer to the problem is exactly the same.